# docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/grafana" is already in use by container "f6b2d471d737a"

Tags: graphite

Please I really need your help when I try to execute  this command

root@Graphite:~# docker run -d\

> --name graphite
> --restart=always
> -v /path/to/graphite/configs:/opt/graphite/conf
> -v /path/to/graphite/data:/opt/graphite/storage
> -v /path/to/statsd_config:/opt/statsd/config
> graphiteapp/graphite-statsd

I receive this message

docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/grafana" is already in use by container "f6b2d471d737a". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

please I need your help I've used Docker to install graphite it's working but I want files to be locally and I don't have this much knowledge about linux this why I need your help

Comment: Is your error message correct? It looks like you are trying to run a container with the name graphite but the error message complains about grafana! Maybe you could check docker ps -a and find the container with the id from the error message. If it is not running, you can remove it with docker rm <container-id>

Comment: This is the error message 
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/graphite" is                                                                                                                                                                              already in use by container "100760b0". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reus                                                                                                                                                                             e that name.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Okay, then the error makes sense. There is already a container with that name! either remove the existing container (docker rm <container-id>) or choose a different name (e.g. --name graphite2)

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
docker stop 100760b0 graphite
docker rm 100760b0 graphite
```

Then retry your command.