# Docker: Error response from daemon - why is it not showing in docker container ls?

Tags: docker

I have read this post and I have a similar problem :

[docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/grafana" is already in use by container "f6b2d471d737a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109107/docker-error-response-from-daemon-conflict-the-container-name-grafana-is-a)

and I have the same error. Why is this container not showing, when I type:

```
docker container ls
```

is there an option to show all containers ?

Comment: Exited/Errored containers wont show up with above command.  Use `docker container ls -a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see only running containers:

```
$ docker container ls
```

To see all containers:

```
$ docker container ls -a
```

`-a` as in all. You need to use the second command in this situation.